# Does Jetbrains Rider support configuring Local IIS Debugging?

Tags: iis, intellij-idea, ide, rider

I'm trying Jetbrains Rider 2017.  One of the features I have used in Visual Studio for many years is the ability to configure easily building and debugging a website in IIS (instead of Cassini/IIS Express), without needing to go through the whole "Attach to Process" flow.  This is done in the project web configuration, setting the host to Local IIS and providing the URL, and the configuration stored in the csproj.user file.

Can this be achieved in Rider, and if so how?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-8443

Comment: Thanks Iven.  Not yet, but it's in the pipeline seems to be the gist of it.

Comment: Yes we are looking at switching to Rider from VS, but debugging against a local IIS instance is a requirement for us.